# Is it possible to group Plone portlet fields into fieldsets?

Tags: plone, portlet

I have a very long portlet edit screen so I'd like to group its fields using fieldsets (and then probably layouting those into native form tabs, like those used in content's edit view).

Is this possible with zope.formlib?

Comment: There is also z3c.form aware portlets nowadays. Jump there. I have made it backwards compatible back to P3.3.

Comment: I prefer to stick to formlib if possible. The effort of getting off-road isn't worth in this case. I'd prefer to take on a Javascript DOM modification approach.

Comment: Portlets support z3c.form natively since Plone 4.3 (or Plone 4.2)

Comment: Can't see that on [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/docs/CHANGES.rst). Any docs?

Comment: This: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11838 - See imageportlet package for P3.3 backport

Comment: Ok, this is what I'd need to inherit from in order to to use z3c.form based portlets: https://github.com/plone/plone.app.portlets/blob/master/plone/app/portlets/browser/z3cformhelper.py However I'm still curious to know if it'd be doable using `zope.formlib` only.

Comment: How about using/mimicrying plone.fieldsets and gocept.form.grouped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To conclude, the answer for Plone 4 really is to use z3c.form based portlets and create fieldsets by inheriting the form schema from plone.supermodel.model.Schema and defining the fieldsets using plone.autoform.directives.fieldset: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.autoform#organizing-fields-into-fieldsets

The support for them was introduced in plone.app.portlets 2.3 (while the latest Plone 4 version during writing is 2.5.1).

It should be enough to use a following z3c.form based portlet form base classes instead of the formlib ones:

```
from plone.app.portlets.browser.z3cformhelper import AddForm
from plone.app.portlets.browser.z3cformhelper import EditForm
```

It's also good to know that z3c.form based portlets will be the default in Plone 5 (and base classes in z3cformhelper are made the default base classes).